# wordpress dev to live

Tags: php, wordpress, deployment

I have a wordpress local dev and a wordpress production environment.  all the local work is in the form of a theme.  My question is, when I want to push it live is all I need to do:

1. Install the local theme on live site
2. Dump and install the local db on live site
3. Update the live config file

The reason I am asking is: doesn't wordpress keep domain info in the db too?  So is my local is dev.example.com and live is www.example.com would the local db work on the live site with no alterations to the data?

Comment: Personally, I've found XCloner to be the best solution for moving a Wordpress site between servers. It's in the plugin repository. Just make sure you deactivate and remove it once you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some modifications to `wp_options` table too. "siteurl" and "home" rows are the ones who store the domain info.

You can modify this by executing the following query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'www.example.com' WHERE option_name IN ('siteurl', 'home')
```

Comment: is that the only table that will initially store the domain info?

Comment: Usually it is. However, if you have absolute URLs in your posts, you'll also have to replace the domain in wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables. In this case, the tool Justin Carboneau mentioned should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run a search and replace on the database after you've imported it on the live site, to replace your development URL with the live URL.

I've written a simple tool to generate the SQL queries you need:
http://exygy.com/sql-generator-tool-for-wordpress-migrations/

The tool above doesn't replace URLs in serialized arrays, but I've found that's not a problem for 99.9% of sites.

There's also a free tool that does replace URLs in serialized arrays, though it's a bit more overhead to set up:
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Do you now which tables typically have the url in them?  Can I just create the new site using wordpress on live and simply copy the posts and pages tables (and any other non-settings tables)?

Answer (score 1):

In line with the answers posted above, you can do it in following ways:

1). The easiest way is to use a script( after you have moved the site over to production), and it will search for all the instances of old domain in the db in all the db tables and will work like a charm. I personally prefer this option. One

2). You can also manually run a search for the old domain name in the db and replace it with the new one. On a simple website, you only need to do that in wp_options table, but you site can have references in other tables as well depending on your theme and plugins. I would do the search thru every table.